# Why do I get two Tk app windows open on Mac OSX

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

when I run the following code to create a menu in Mac OSX, I get 2 TK app windows popping up, I only want one.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
win = Toplevel(root)
menubar = Menu(win)
appmenu = Menu(menubar, name='apple')
menubar.add_cascade(menu=appmenu)
appmenu.add_command(label='About My Application')
appmenu.add_separator()
win['menu'] = menubar

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a window:

```
root = Tk()
```

... and this is a window:

```
win = Toplevel(root)
```

If you want just one window, don't create the `Toplevel`.